# Sort xml nodes in particular order

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not very good in xslt, following is my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="printJob">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="printDoc[@type!='adhoc']" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="printDoc[@type='adhoc']">
        
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The basic purpose of my xslt is transform my xml such that all **printdoc** element with attribute **@Type='adhoc'** should be last in their parent(printJob) list, all other element should retrieve their existing order.

My current xslt is working fine, when my all my printDoc elements contains "Type" attribute, but in some xml, "Type" attribute is missing for "printDoc" element.

Comment: `[@Type!='adhoc']` means there must be a `Type` attribute with a value other than `adhoc`. `[not(@Type='adhoc')]` also covers the case where there is no `Type` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2 indeed, as your version in the code suggests, then I think the literal implementation of your requirement would be to simply use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="* except printDoc[@type='adhoc'], printDoc[@type='adhoc']"/>
```

[XSLT 3 sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%20method%3D%22xml%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22printJob%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22*%20except%20printDoc%5B%40type%3D%27adhoc%27%5D%2C%20printDoc%5B%40type%3D%27adhoc%27%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%20%20%3CprintJob%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cfoo%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CprintDoc%20type%3D%22adhoc%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CprintDoc%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbar%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CprintDoc%20type%3D%22adhoc%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CprintDoc%20type%3D%22whatever%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2FprintJob%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E&input-type=XML) (could replace `xsl:mode` declaration with your identity template for XSLT 2).

For XSLT 1 I would use

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::printDoc[@type='adhoc'])]"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="printDoc[@type='adhoc']"/>
```

Comment: Getting following error.
Expected end of the expression, found 'except '.

Comment: @ChetanMehra, which XSLT 2 processor do you use, which error exactly do you get?

Comment: @ChetanMehra, that suggests you are not using an XSLT 2 processor, no idea why you present code using `version="2.0"` in your question. Anyway, see the edit of the answer for an XSLT 1.0 alternative.